# React. Why Did You Render. Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, callstack

I'm using React and when am rendering table (with react-table library) I've got warning from why-did-you-render library.

There is a react-table column with Cell field, where I pass my memoized component.

```
[
    {
      accessor: 'firstName',
      Header: 'First Name',
      Cell: EditableTd,
    }
  ]

const isEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.value === nextProps.value;
};

const EditableTd = ({column, value}) => (
    <CellContentWrapper>
      {column?.valueFormatter?.(value) || value}
      <IconWrapper>
        <IconButton type="edit" data-testid="test-edit" title="Edit" />
      </IconWrapper>
    </CellContentWrapper>
);

export default React.memo(EditableTd, isEqual);
```

"Cell" signature

```
Cell: Function | React.Component => JSX
```

react-table implementation

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
  {rows.map((row) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}}>
                        <div>{cell.render('Cell')}</div>
                      </td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
</tbody>
```

I sort table data on server side and when I get new data and table rerenders I've got such warning:

```
> Warning: why-did-you-render couldn't handle circular references in
> props. RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded 
>     at WDYRFunctionalComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render/dist/whyDidYouRender.js:1150:33)
>     at div
>     at td
>     at tr
>     at tbody
>     at table
       ...
```

App works without lags and browser doesn't show any warnings. Can't figure out is it problem in my code or is this warning only about the library?

Thanks

UPD
Сreated simple sandbox with this behaviour. Need to sort table
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9bknpa?file=components/table.js

Comment: Can you show us how do you use this library and with what props?

Comment: Hi! Added more info to description

Comment: I can make a guess from your code that `prepareRow` could be possible culprit.

Comment: Please post the code for to `prepareRow` so that we can help you further.

Comment: Hi! I've created sandbox with this behavior. Try to sort table and watch console output. https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9bknpa?file=components/table.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your application , the problem is in the way `why-did-you-render` compares props of `react.memo` , it attempts to do a deep compare which results in an infinite loop because of self reference in the data structure of props passed to `Cell` component. It seems the error is the one you can ignore , but you can test your app in production mode to make sure error goes away.